# How to match everything except single character but not inside double quoted string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not able to find a similar question. I have a regex like this:

```
const re = /(\$\{([^\}]+)\})/
```

I'm trying to add better regex for string interpolation into my [Scheme based lisp interpreter](https://lips.js.org/), it should work like JavaScript template literals `${...}`. I want to match everything that is not `"}"` but not inside double quotes.
I use `String::split()` on a bigger string, so I need to extract all the matches.

Example expressions that should match:

- `${(string-append "{" "hello" "}")}`
- `${(+ 1 2)}`

Example of a full string:

- `"x = ${(+ 1 2)}; y = ${(+ 2 3)}; s = ${(string-append "{" "hello" "}")}"`

Can you do this with a single regex? Or do I need to have a small parser for it?

Comment: *"it should work like JavaScript template literals"*: so should it support nested template literals?

Comment: @trincot good question, I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 1):

While writing the question I found my old string literals regex (in the old version of my interpreter):

```
const string_re = /"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"])*"/g;
```

With this, I came up with this regular expression:

```js
const re = /(\$\{((?:"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"])*"|[^\}])+)\})/
```

Here is a [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ooA49a/1).